# Multiple checkbox selection at AJAX when button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

```
    <script>
        function display() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "tmp.php",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    a: $('#selecttmp option:selected').val()
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data);
                alert(data);

                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('.#buttontmp').click(function() {
                    $('.data').prop('checked', this.checked);
                  });
                });
              });
            }
    </script>
```

[image]

When `button` is clicked, it reads the `select option value` and check up every relevant checkbox based on their `name`.

Using AJAX, `select option value` could be found without any refresh but checkboxes aren't checked. Am I using `jquery` wrongly?

Comment: `$('.#buttontmp').click()` - what elements are you trying to select here? You probably need to make up your mind, whether you want to use the class or the ID selector.

Comment: And why are you adding a click handler at this point anyway? You want the checkboxes to get checked immediately, and not just after an additional button click - no?

Comment: @CBroe Event need to occur by clcikcing the button After selecting items from `select menu` and then relevant checkbox needs to be checked. 

Thus I thought `Click` was appropriate approach.

Comment: But you did already click, to trigger this AJAX request in the first place. So why add additional click handlers now, when the request is finished? You want to change the checked state of the checkboxes at this point - so do _that_, and _just_ that.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your correction. I have posted my solution! Great thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script>
        function display() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    a: $('#selectest option:selected').val()
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data);
                alert(data);

                $('input:checkbox[name='+data+']').each(function() {
                  this.checked = true;
                });
              });
            }
    </script>
```

I have figure out the solution myself, thanks for the correction that made by @CBroe.